# How to get tagged pages in an event description using Facebook graph API?

Tags: json, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, events

We are a french start up which built an app that tells to our users which musical artists are around them, wherever they are. 
We use Facebook Graph API to get some informations about Facebook events to complete our content. Our only way to detect artists name on an FB event description is when the Facebook link or the SoundCloud link is directly written. 
The problem is that a lot of event producers just tag the artists pages on their descriptions without giving the real links. With Facebook Graph API we are unable to get the pages tagged in descriptions as links. 
It would be very useful for us if we were able to get it. Do you have any solution ?

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You must do get special facebook permission for get pages with fb api.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Thx.